# GMP - mpf_cmp_si not working correctly for negative values

Tags: rust, gmp

I'm using the GNU multiple precision library through Rust, and I'm trying to write a wrapper for the mpf_sqrt() function.
In order to do so, I need to make sure the number is positive, but `mpf_cmp_si()` isn't behaving.

EDIT: new example

```
extern crate libc;
use libc::{c_double, c_int, c_long, c_ulong, c_void,c_char};
use std::mem::uninitialized;

type mp_limb_t = usize; // TODO: Find a way to use __gmp_bits_per_limb instead.
type mp_bitcnt_t = c_ulong;
type mp_exp_t = c_long;

#[link(name = "gmp")]
extern "C" {
    fn __gmpf_init2(x: mpf_ptr, prec: mp_bitcnt_t);
    fn __gmpf_set_si(rop: mpf_ptr,op: c_int);
    fn __gmpf_cmp_si(op1: mpf_srcptr, op2: c_long) -> c_int;
}

#[repr(C)]
pub struct mpf_struct {
    _mp_prec: c_int,
    _mp_size: c_int,
    _mp_exp: mp_exp_t,
    _mp_d: *mut c_void
}

pub type mpf_srcptr = *const mpf_struct;
pub type mpf_ptr = *mut mpf_struct;

fn main() {
    let mut ten:mpf_struct;
    unsafe{
        ten = uninitialized();
        __gmpf_init2(&mut ten,512);
        __gmpf_set_si(&mut ten,10);
    }
    let mut minus_ten:mpf_struct;
    unsafe{
        minus_ten = uninitialized();
        __gmpf_init2(&mut minus_ten,512);
        __gmpf_set_si(&mut minus_ten,-10);
    }


    // compare things
    unsafe{
        println!("Result of comparison of -10 (mpf) and 10 (signed int) = {}",
            __gmpf_cmp_si(&minus_ten,10));
        println!("Result of comparison of -10 (mpf) and 0 (signed int) = {}",
            __gmpf_cmp_si(&minus_ten,0));
        println!("Result of comparison of 10 (mpf) and 0 (signed int) = {}",
            __gmpf_cmp_si(&ten,0));
    }


}
```

This returns:

```
Running `target/debug/so_test`
Result of comparison of -10 (mpf) and 10 (signed int) = 1
Result of comparison of -10 (mpf) and 0 (signed int) = 1
Result of comparison of 10 (mpf) and 0 (signed int) = 1
```

According to the docs, this is the behavior:

> ```
> Function: int mpf_cmp_si (const mpf_t op1, signed long int op2)
> Compare op1 and op2. Return a positive value if op1 > op2, zero if op1 = op2, and a negative value if op1 < op2.
> ```

I'm running rust 1.4.0, and GMP 6.1.0-1 on x64 Linux

Old code:

> ```
>     pub fn sqrt(self) -> Mpf {
>     let mut retval:Mpf;
>     unsafe {
>         retval = Mpf::new(__gmpf_get_prec(&self.mpf) as usize);
>         retval.set_from_si(0);
>         if __gmpf_cmp_ui(&self.mpf,0) > 0 {
>             __gmpf_sqrt(&mut retval.mpf,&self.mpf);
>         } else {
>             panic!("Square root of negative/zero");
>         }
>     }
>     retval
> }
> ```
>
> the mpf struct is defined like this:
>
> ```
> #[repr(C)]
> pub struct mpf_struct {
>     _mp_prec: c_int,
>     _mp_size: c_int,
>     _mp_exp: mp_exp_t,
>     _mp_d: *mut c_void
> } and the function from gmp is imported like this:
>
> #[link(name = "gmp")]
> extern "C" {
>     fn __gmpf_cmp_si(op1: mpf_srcptr, op2: c_long) -> c_int;
>
> }
> ```
>
> The problem I'm having is that `mpf_cmp_si` (which is exposed to Rust
>   as `__gmpf_cmp_si`) doesn't return negative when it should.
>
> This function should return negative if the value of my mpf is less
>   than 0. But it doesn't so the function divides by zero and crashes (an
>   "unknown error", not because of the panic!() call)

Comment: Could you make a smaller more self contained example? E.g. `fn main() { let mut val = Mpf::new(...); val.set_from_si(0); println!("{}", __gmpf_cmp_ui(&self.mpf, 0));`.

Comment: does the equivalent code in c work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of `__gmpf_set_si` is incorrect. The C definition is:

```
void mpf_set_si (mpf_t rop, signed long int op)
```

And hence the Rust FFI declaration should use `c_long`, not `c_int`:

```
fn __gmpf_set_si(rop: mpf_ptr,op: c_long);
```

Making this change makes the output (plus a few extra prints) as follows:

```
Result of comparison of -10 (mpf) and -10 (signed int) = 0
Result of comparison of -10 (mpf) and 0 (signed int) = -1
Result of comparison of -10 (mpf) and 10 (signed int) = -1
Result of comparison of 10 (mpf) and -10 (signed int) = 1
Result of comparison of 10 (mpf) and 0 (signed int) = 1
Result of comparison of 10 (mpf) and 10 (signed int) = 0
```

(NB. adding the comparisons against `-10`/`10` was how I got to the bottom of this: they failed for `-10` compared to `-10`.)

The problem is `int` and `long` aren't necessarily the same: on 64-bit platforms, they are typically 32-bits and 64-bits respectively. In either case, the argument is passed in the same (64-bit) register, but the type mismatch means that the register is only initialised with a 32-bit -10, which is very different to a 64-bit one. The bit patterns of each are:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111111110110
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110110
```

When interpreted as a signed 64-bit integer (like `gmpf_set_si` does internally), the first one is 2<sup>32</sup> - 10 = 4294967286, which is exactly what `minus_ten` is initialised with:

```
extern crate libc;
use libc::{c_double, c_int, c_long, c_ulong, c_void,c_char};
use std::mem::uninitialized;

type mp_limb_t = usize; // TODO: Find a way to use __gmp_bits_per_limb instead.
type mp_bitcnt_t = c_ulong;
type mp_exp_t = c_long;

#[link(name = "gmp")]
extern "C" {
    fn __gmpf_init2(x: mpf_ptr, prec: mp_bitcnt_t);
    fn __gmpf_set_si(rop: mpf_ptr,op: c_int);
    fn __gmp_printf(x: *const c_char, ...);
}

#[repr(C)]
pub struct mpf_struct {
    _mp_prec: c_int,
    _mp_size: c_int,
    _mp_exp: mp_exp_t,
    _mp_d: *mut c_void
}
pub type mpf_ptr = *mut mpf_struct;


fn main() {
    unsafe{
        let mut ten = uninitialized();
        __gmpf_init2(&mut ten,512);
        __gmpf_set_si(&mut ten,10);

        let mut minus_ten = uninitialized();
        __gmpf_init2(&mut minus_ten,512);
        __gmpf_set_si(&mut minus_ten,-10);

        __gmp_printf(b"10 == %Ff\n-10 == %Ff\n".as_ptr() as *const c_char,
                     &ten, &minus_ten);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
10 == 10.000000
-10 == 4294967286.000000
```

As a final point, [rust-bindgen](https://github.com/crabtw/rust-bindgen) is a great tool for avoiding errors in mechanical transcriptions like this: it will generate the right things based on a C header.

Comment: *on 64-bit platforms, they are typically 32-bits and 64-bits respectively* — that may be better stated as "on 64-bit **Linux** and **OS X** platforms"; Visual Studio on Windows treats `long` as 32-bit because of the previous transition from 16 to 32 bit :-)